# Perl: multidimensional hash

Tags: perl, hash, multidimensional-array

suppose I have the following data

**cluster1:d(A),f(C)s,(A)**

**cluster2:r(D),h(D),f(A)**

I want this out put

output:

```
   cluster1:A->2
   cluster1:C->1
   cluster2:D->2
   cluster2:A->1
```

here is my try,but it is not correct , the part that I am trying to count characters has a problem that I cant fix
the code is a part of very big code ,and I want exactly multidimensional hash

```
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
 my %count;
while (<DATA>) {
    my %HoH;
    my ( $cluster, $ch ) = split (/:/,$_);
    $HoH{$cluster}={split /[()]+/,$ch}; 
    for my $clust ( keys %HoH ) {
        for my $character ( keys %{ $HoH{$clust} } ) {
            $count{$clust}{$HoH{$clust}{$character}}++;
     }
    }
}
print Dumper(\%count);
foreach my $name (sort keys %count) {
    foreach my $subject (keys %{$count{$name}}) {
        print "$name:$subject->$count{$name}{$subject}\n";
    }
}
```

**DATA**

cluster1:d(A),f(C)s,(A)

cluster2:r(D),h(D),f(A)

Comment: The input format is also very different now.

Comment: @flesk:yes, I should have written every thing from the begining now this code works  with a small bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be nice if you try to understand the below code so that you can get an idea for solving the problem:-

```
    use strict;
    use Data::Dumper;

    my $data = "cluster1:A,B,C,A";
    my %cluster = ();

    my ($cluster_key, $cluster_val ) = split (':', $data);
    my @cluster1_data = split(',', $cluster_val);


    foreach my $val ( @cluster1_data ) {
    $cluster{$cluster_key}{$val}++;
    }
    print Dumper(\%cluster);


    foreach my $clus ( keys %cluster ) {
    my $clus_ref = $cluster{$clus};
        foreach my $clu ( keys %{ $clus_ref } ){
          my $count = $clus_ref->{$clu};
          print"$clus:$clu->$count\n";
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'cluster1' => {
                          'A' => 2,
                          'C' => 1,
                          'B' => 1
                        }
        };


cluster1:A->2
cluster1:C->1
cluster1:B->1
```

Comment: I have edited my question and also my code would you please see whats the problem

Answer (score 1):

What do you expect `$count{$cluster}{$characters}+=1;` to do exactly? You have to loop over your input data to populate `%count` if you expect to get the desired result:

```
while (<DATA>) {
    next unless /^(cluster\d+):(.+)/;
    $count{$1}{$_}++ for split/,/, $2;
}
```

If you also add `sort` to the second `foreach` you'll get the output you want.

**EDIT:** This solves the question for the updated input and requirements:

```
my %count;

while (<DATA>) {
    next unless /^(cluster\d+):(.+)/;
    my $cluster = $1;
    $count{$cluster}{$_}++ for $2 =~ /\((\w)\)/g;
}

for my $key (sort keys %count) {
    for my $value (sort {
        $count{$key}{$b} <=> $count{$key}{$a}
                   } keys %{$count{$key}}) {
        print "$key:$value->$count{$key}{$value}\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: @shaq: refer to http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Special-Literals if you are confused by the `<DATA>` thing.

Comment: no I am not confused by data, but I would be wondering if you could update the code,suppose I have the cluster thing in $cluster and characters in $character the after for what should I write

Comment: @simbabque: Good point. Also if you're reading your data from a filehandle, replace `DATA` with the name of the filehandle. Oh, and I just noticed that the characters aren't sorted, so I'm not sure what the logic behind the ordering is?

Comment: @shaq: You could write `$count{$cluster}{$_}++ for split/,/, $characters;` to achieve that.